# Trigger an animation on element click?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events, effects

I am using the above code http://jsfiddle.net/raybellis/tF833/ in order to be able to trigger click event without clicking but with a delay on hover. In order to make it more clear to user experience I would like to trigger a simple animation (it doesn't really matter what the effect will be) like a fade out in the selected element or a target pointer that focuses on the specific element or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work from jQuery UI?

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```